# How to remove certain fields when doing serialization to a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model in my Django app:

```
class Policy(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "policies"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()
    content = models.TextField()

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name, last_update, content):
        policy = cls(name=name, last_update=last_update, content=content)
        return policy
```

Now, I have a datatable, where I fill the rows using this function from  views.py:

```
def myModel_asJson(request):
    object_list = Policy.objects.all() #or any kind of queryset
    json = serializers.serialize('json', object_list)
    return HttpResponse(json, content_type='application/json')
```

However, my data table doesn't contain content column.
My question is - how can I omit the content field from my model when I do the serialization? Is there any other approach I can use to return JSON representation of my models without the content field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify fields which will be returned with `fields` argument of `serialize` method:

```
json = serializers.serialize('json', object_list, fields=('field1', 'field2'))
```